# How to add asp image to html element from code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to add asp image control to simple div element and show it on page but instead of image I am getting `System.Image.Web.Image`.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "~/" + p.Image.Medium;
result += "<div class='box'>" + img + "<p>" + p.Name + "</p></div>";
```

Is it possible to add image to div in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because at this stage, the String representation of this object is a `System.Image.Web.Image`. You're just going to create a string representation (of not only the Image object but of the entire expression) and then pass it down to the stream. That is why, it is being displayed as a string not the Image.

Anyways, you can manipulate the DOM, using the objects that will be passed down as HTML objects, such as PlaceHolder objects, and into their Children collection add this control. For example this one,

```
// instantiating the control
Image img = new Image(); 
// setting the path to the image
img.ImageUrl = "~/" + p.Image.Medium; 
// add the image to a PlaceHolder object, here placeHolder1
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(img);
```

Hopefully this helps you out to understand using the code. :)